# I want to keep only a value in a column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column with values that look like this: "(42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667"
I want to keep only the number beside ms inside the cell :42837666.84 and remove the time stamp and ms and the ()
how can i do that in the whole column knowing that it is random ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`, example below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col': ["(42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667", "(42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

                             col
0  (42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667
1  (42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667

#here you split twice, once on 'ms' and retrun 0
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split('ms').str[0]
#here you split on '(' and return 1
df['col']  = df['col'].str.split('(').str[1]

print(df)
            col
0  42837666.84 
1  42837666.84
```

Comment: It gave me the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: beacuse you need to change 'col' to the actual name of your column!

Comment: Of course i did that in the first part but when i change it in the part df.col.str.split('ms').str[0] it gives me an invalid syntax that's why i left the second one

Comment: It’s probably because your column name has space in it, change the code to df[‘column name’].str

Comment: I don't understand the column name is HW Timestamp do u mean th code line should be : df['HW Timestamp'].str = df.HW Timestamp.str.split('ms').str[0] ?

Comment: do this:   df['HW Timestamp'] = df['HW Timestamp'].str.split('ms').str[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use combination of `partition` and `strip` :

```
value =  "(42837666.84 ms) 11:53:57.667"
value = value.partition('ms')[0]
value = value.strip('()')
print(value)
```

Output:
`42837666.84`

- `partition` is a simplified `split` - to cut out anything you don't need
- `strip` will remove the `separator` from the start and the end of string

You can try to use different argument than `'ms'` for partition, which suits you best.

Comment: when i tried that but instead of value the whole column containing the values i got this error" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition' "

Comment: @HebaR `partition` is method of `string` so it won't work with list.